# Let $k: = \mathbb{Q} (ς)$ and $K: = k [\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Show that $K\cong k [X] / <X^3-2>$ and $K\otimes_k K\cong K\times K\times K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, tensor-products, tensors, group-homomorphism

Let $X$ be a variable, $ς$ a cubic root of the unit and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ the real cubic root of $2$. Let $k: = \mathbb{Q} (ς)$ and $K: = k [\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Show that $K\cong  k [X] / <X^3-2>$ and $K\otimes_k K\cong K\times K\times K$.

I do not understand what $\mathbb{Q} (ς)$ and $k [\sqrt[3]{2}]$ mean, Could someone explain me please? 
Would be the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that its root is $ς$?
To show that $K\cong  k [X] / <X^3-2>$ 
We could take an homomorphism $\varphi : k[X]\rightarrow K$ and prove that its nucleus is $<X^3-2>$?
I had thought that the function $\varphi$ is the one that takes a polynomial and evaluates it in a number but I do not know which one, could take an arbitrary one? 
And to test the second part I thought of using the universal property of the tensor product but I do not know which function to define in the Cartesian product, what do you think?

Comment: $\zeta$ is a root of $X^2 + X +1$.  (These are called [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).)  As a hint, note that $\frac{K[X]}{(X^3 - 2)} = \frac{K[X]}{((X - \sqrt[3]{2})(X - \zeta \sqrt[3]{2})(X - \zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2}))} \cong \frac{K[X]}{(X - \sqrt[3]{2})} \times \frac{K[X]}{(X - \zeta \sqrt[3]{2})} \times \frac{K[X]}{(X - \zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2}))} \cong \cdots$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ is, essentially, "polynomials in $\zeta$". Since $\zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 = 0$, higher powers of $\zeta$ (such as $\zeta^3,\zeta^4$, etc.) can be reduced down to powers under $3$. It should be clear that if we define $\varphi: k[X] \to K$ by: $\varphi(p(X)) = p(\sqrt[3]{2})$ then $\langle X^3 - 2\rangle \in \text{ker }\varphi$. Can you show the other inclusion?